# Can a BizTalk Receive Port pull in FailedMessageRoutings like a Send Port does with filtering?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

Is there anyway for a BizTalk receive port to initialize an orchestration, pulling in FailedMessages that could otherwise be routed to a send port in the console using filtering on ErrorType exists and the origional port name where it occurred? Or is this only possible on send ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with receive ports.  It is, however, possible by direct binding the Orchestration's receive port to the message box and setting the appropriate filters. In a nut shell, set up the orchestartion to be callable with a direct bound port attached to the activating receive shape.  Set the filters on the receive shape to make the message box subscription be what you'd like.

For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa949234(v=BTS.20).aspx